# What's the meaning of よーちぇん時 and おらん?

Tags: time, kansai-ben

I am reading something but I can't decipher the meaning of this: よーちぇん時から忘れた事ないぞ、みーくん and おらん

The first one I can grasp the sense since it tells Mi-kun not to forget the time but  よーちぇん is affixed before 時. Upon searching google, many of the searches returns something about time like "おはよーちぇんだよ".

On the second one, I am confused if this means "I" as おら is a northen dialect for 俺. However, the speaker speaks in Kansa-ben so maybe that's not it. I know there's おる in Kansai-ben which means いる in standard dialect. With ん affixed to it, does it mean negates おる?

Comment: Full context would be useful (for みーくん and おらん). They are also likely separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never seen よーちぇん before but it must be a lazy pronunciation of 幼稚園{ようちえん}

So: "I haven't forgotten it since kindergarten"

And no context in the question but おらん will most likely be the negative of おる, yes.

Comment: I did some googling and I think you're correct with よーちぇん. I will mark this as accepted answer if there'll be no other asnwers. :)

Comment: I did some googling too after I answered and I'm pretty sure I'm right with よーちぇん. よーちぇん時 would be 幼稚園の時 :)

Comment: It's definitely 幼稚園

Comment: おらん is often いない in Kansai-ben.

Answer (score 2):

Spouse of a Kansai-ben speaker here and I can confirm おらん is the normal way of saying いない. If the speaker is supposed to be from Kansai then that must be it.